# ListView.Items.Add() showing WpfApplication1.Mainwindow+Item instead of my values

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a ListView and I try to add items programmatically in it.The problem is that instead of my values, the listview is showing *WpfApplication2.MainWindow+Item* instead of my values.

This is the code I use to add the items:

```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemL item = new ItemL
        {
            ID = 1,
            NAME = "Test",
            PING = "Test"
        };
        ServerLister.Items.Add(item);

    }
    public class ItemL
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string NAME { get; set; }

        public string PING { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my listView XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ServerLister" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LVitem}" Height="520" Margin="10,130,10,0" FontSize="28"  FontFamily="/WpfApplication2;component/Resources/#Purista SemiBold" Background="#66181F2C" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1.000001" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView  ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeader}" AllowsColumnReorder="False" >
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" ID" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" NAME" Width="500"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NAME}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header=" PING" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PING}"  />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
```

This is the ItemContainerStyle :

```
  <Style x:Key="LVitem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#663F5768" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#992E4051" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ItemContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#66597B93" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#99364B5F" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>

                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDADADA" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>

                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: This code should work! where is it showing asWpfApplication2.MainWindow+Item . Post your ItemsContainer style aswell

Comment: Well, it looks like this: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img842/5334/9idf.png , I renamed MainWindow to LauncherTest thats why in image its not .MainWindow.

Comment: post your ItemContainerStyle

Comment: I edited the post with the ItemContainerStyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment , problem lies in your ItemsContainerStyle,

change **Content** **Presenter** in you style to **GridViewRowPresenter**

```
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
<Grid>
<Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
<GridViewRowPresenter />
</Border>
</Grid>
</Grid>
```